# Matching a few letters and letters with numbers

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I'm trying to match letters C D F H I E1 E2 CR (case insensitive) and came up with this. It'll match a single letter but wont match the E1 E2 CR. Actually it should. Whats the right way to do this?

```
preg_match('/^([C]|[D]|[F]|[H]|[I]|[E1]|[E2]|[CR]?)$/','CR')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the fairly limited and specific set of codes you're checking, I'd suggest using

```
in_array($inputvalue,array('C','D','F','H','I','E1','E2','CR'));
```

rather than a regex -- it'll run quicker than a regex and be easier to undersand and modify later on.

Comment: I like the simplicity over regex here. Just be sure to `strtoupper($inputvalue)` first.

Comment: Thanks for pointng me to the in_array function. Its a lot easier than regex.

Answer (score 6):

`[...]` defines a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which tells the regular expression engine to match one element within the class. For that reason, `[E1]` actually means *match E or 1*. Since you want to match `E1` and `E2`, you can combine those conditions to `E[12]` (ie. `E` followed by `1` or `2`). Furthermore, you can simplify all your single letter classes by combining them together. Also, if you add the `/i` [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) at the end of your pattern, that will make it case-insensitive.

```
preg_match('/^([CDFHI]|E[12]|CR)?$/i', 'CR');
```

Note that the `?` at the end of the pattern makes the preceding group [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). Note that by making part of the pattern optional (as you seem to be trying to do in your question) or the whole pattern optional (like I do in my solution), an empty string will be matched by this pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
preg_match('/^(C|D|F|H|I|E1|E2|CR)$/i','CR')
```

- A char class with single char like
  `[x]` is same as `x`
- Use the `i` modifier to make the
  matching case insensitive.